# How to segregate data from long sized csv file in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, sed, grep, terminal

I have a `.csv` file around 30GB of size. I wanted to grep some lines which should follow multiple string matching condition. What could the correct way to do it using `grep`, `awk` or `sed`? I tried following command which is returning the result but its showing earlier dated data as well.

`grep -w "for-outbound-sports\|2019-05-16" Master.csv`

Is there any other way to do it faster using `awk` or `sed` or something else?

**Updated**

More specifically the sample Input:

```
"","22288","1990353330","for-outbound-STARZONE","22288","Local/1990353330@for-outbound-STARZONE-00042f49;2","DAHDI/i15/01990353330-c237","Dial","DAHDI/G0/01990353330,30","2019-01-17 13:45:05","2019-01-17 13:45:17","2019-01-17 13:45:32",27,15,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1547732705.828852",""
"","22020","1990353330","for-outbound-sports","22020","Local/1990353330@for-outbound-sports-001b223f;2","DAHDI/i14/01990353330-553f8","Dial","DAHDI/G0/01990353330,30","2019-05-15 03:57:02","2019-05-15 03:57:10","2019-05-15 03:57:44",42,34,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1557979022.5390225",""
"","22020","1990353330","for-outbound-sports","22020","Local/1990353330@for-outbound-sports-001b223f;2","DAHDI/i14/01990353330-553f8","Dial","DAHDI/G0/01990353330,30","2019-05-16 03:57:02","2019-05-16 03:57:10","2019-05-16 03:57:44",42,34,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1557979022.5390225",""
```

Sample Output:

```
"","22020","1990353330","for-outbound-sports","22020","Local/1990353330@for-outbound-sports-001b223f;2","DAHDI/i14/01990353330-553f8","Dial","DAHDI/G0/01990353330,30","2019-05-16 03:57:02","2019-05-16 03:57:10","2019-05-16 03:57:44",42,34,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1557979022.5390225",""
```

Answer (score 2):

`grep` is already a really fast way to go through big files and find words or characters in lines, maybe the `-w` word-regexp makes it a bit slow. Often it is not the `grep` itself which is slow, it is mostly the output on the terminal. You can simply test it by direct the output to a file:

`grep -w "for-outbound-sports\|2019-05-16" Master.csv > greped_master.csv`

You have always the possibility to use the programm `parallel` to split the big file and make use of multithreading.
e.g.
`parallel --pipe --block 2M grep foo < bigfile`
As you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066609/fastest-possible-grep)

Comment: I observed that the command `grep -w "for-outbound-sports\|2019-05-16" Master.csv > greped_master.csv` is not detecting the mentioned date, its detecting previous date as well. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: I think thats because you are looking for lines where is the word 'for-outbound-sports' OR '2019-05-16'.
If in a row are one of the upper words, you will get the result.
If you want to get only the lines where both words are matching you need to use an AND.
`grep -w "for-outbound-sports" Master.csv | grep -w "2019-05-16"`
or in one command
`grep -Ew "for-outbound-sports.*2019-05-16" Master.csv`